# How can sed replace "\ " (backslash + space)?

Tags: sed, substitution

In a bash script, files with spaces show up as `"File\ with\ spaces.txt"` and I want to substitute those slashed-spaces with either `_` or `+`.

How can I tell sed to do that? I had no success using;

```
$1=~/File\ with\ spaces.txt
ext=$1
web=$(echo "$ext" | sed 's/\ /+/')
```

I'm open to suggestions if there's a better way than through sed.

[EDIT]: Foo Bah's solution works well, but it substitutes only the first space because the text following it is treated as arguments rather than part of the $1. Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed recognises `\` as space just fine:

```
bee@i20 ~ $ echo file\ 123 | sed 's/\ /+/'
file+123
```

Your bash script syntax is all wrong, though.
Not sure what you were trying to do with the script, but here is an example of replacing spaces with `+`:

```
ext=~/File\ with\ spaces.txt
web=`echo "$ext" | sed 's/\ /+/g'`
echo $web
```

Upd:
Oh, and you need the `g` flag to replace all occurences of space, not only the first one. Fixed above.

Comment: ok, just replace the first line with `ext=$1` then. And run with appropriate argument.

Comment: Still, this replaces only the first space. After that the delimited words are treated as arguments.

Comment: Yay! It was all about the `g` :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: A simple alternative is to use `tr`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252010/38368 i.e. `tr --delete '\\\n'`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/\\\\ /+/';
```

`\\\\` evaluates to a `\\` at the shell level, and then into a literal `\` within sed.

Comment: If you'd used double quotes, you would be right; because you used single quotes, the shell doesn't remove a layer of backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

you want to escape the slash:

```
web=$(echo "$ext" | sed 's/\\ /_/g')
```

Comment: No, that's wrong. That would replace an actual backslash+space.

Comment: That's what the question (or question title) asks for - the output from bash includes a backslash and the combination of backslash+space needs to be replaced with underscore.  OTOH, I suppose there is a possibility that the question (question body) is not quite sure what it needs.

Comment: letitbee's solution worked best. `sed 's/\ /+/g'` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

single quotes are your friend
the following should be used with single quoted args for $1 and $2

```
#!/bin/bash
ESCAPE='\\'
if [ $# -ne 2 ];then   
  echo "$0 <TO_ESCAPE> <IN_STRING>"
  echo args should be in single quotes!! 
  exit 1
fi

TO_ESCAPE="${1}"
IN_STRING="${2}"

if [ ${TO_ESCAPE} = '\' ];then
  TO_ESCAPE='\\'
fi
echo "${IN_STRING}" | sed "s/${TO_ESCAPE}/${ESCAPE}${TO_ESCAPE}/g"
```